# R coding How to add a column and populate it based on values from two other columns

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a table or data frame (df9) with two columns (choice 1 and Choice 2) and want to add a new column which is based filled with values from the first two columns following this logic:

If Choice 1 is populated (not empty), then use Choice 1 value, else, use Choice 2 (whether empty or not).

`Choice1 = c("Blue","","White","")`

`Choice2 = c("Tomato","Apple","Banana","Peach")`

`df9 <- data.frame(Choice1,Choice2)`

Have tried variety of if statements unsuccessfully, not sure how to do a loop thru the table if needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting to character columns will make this a lot less painful.  Then `ifelse()`.  Here I use `nzchar()` to determine non-zero character elements.

```
df9[] <- lapply(df9, as.character)
within(df9, Choice3 <- ifelse(nzchar(Choice1), Choice1, Choice2))
#   Choice1 Choice2 Choice3
# 1    Blue  Tomato    Blue
# 2           Apple   Apple
# 3   White  Banana   White
# 4           Peach   Peach
```

Or just

```
df9$Choice3 <- with(df9, ifelse(nzchar(Choice1), Choice1, Choice2))
```

Note that if you don't convert to character columns, based on your example data, you will receive back the integer values for the factors.

Comment: @PierreLafortune - One of base R's best kept secrets.  Haha, no not really

Comment: @peter Thanks, it worked with df9$Choice3 line better on my real data. The "within" code line put out an error: "[ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 253218 rows ]"